# How to increase the clickable width of an Android spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a `Spinner` which displays single digit numbers (1-6).

When I test on a phone, it's virtually impossible to click on a number because they are so narrow (font size is 12sp) and the only area which appears to be clickable is the text itself.

Ideally I'd like the user to be able click on a greater width on the `Spinner` drop down than just the text. I've tried padding with spaces but these are suppressed, and I've tried using `PaddingLeft/Right` but again there's no difference.

Here is the `Spinner`

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_period1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinner_weekday1"
            android:layout_below="@id/col1day"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/enterperiod"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:entries="@array/periodlist"
            android:layout_marginRight="340dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            />
```

Note that I also set the `Spinner` text attributes using:

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#768766"
        />
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: try fill parent/ match parent attribute instead of wrap content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try making the `TextView` wider in the `android:layout_width` attribute.

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#768766"
        />
```

That could possibly fix your issue or make it better at least.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your TextView layout width to some arbitrary value rather than "wrap_content".  That should make the whole thing clickable, as opposed to just the wrapped content.

Comment: Thanks Barak.If I set the value to, say 200dip then it gives me a much wider selection area, but on a phone I lose the text once it's been selected (i.e. it doesnt appear in the unselected view of the spinner).

However, if I reduce it to something smaller, say 50dip I start to see the text but gets wrapped in the drop-down.

Ideally I'd like to use 200dip, but I don't know why the text would then disappear?

Comment: The solution was actually the one below, using

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

instead of

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: The text is probably centered.  Try aligning it in whichever direction you need using `android:gravity`.

Comment: And if the answer below solved your issue, you should accept it and give prolink007 some credit for it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some padding to the spinner helped me fix this issue.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Way 1:
Display the spinner's options as a dropdown by using **android:spinnerMode**. Therefore have a look at the API ([Android API Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android%3aspinnerMode)). Or play around with **android:dropDownWidth**.

Way 2 (I used it in an APP but at the moment I have no access to the code):
Maybe you could set another layout while populating your spinner with text - instead of assigning the values in the XML.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It's copied from the following link [Android Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#Populate). Maybe you could use one of the layout templates of android.R .